# Correlation network analysis R

Tags: r

I have a correlation network between some clients. I used qgraph to plot it and now I would like to do some graph analysis by defining clusters , hubs and centrality.

I found this R function in the igraph package `edge.betweenness.community` that seems to show clusters in an igraph so I converted my qgraph to an igraph but the function didn't work as I have negative correlation values .

Is there another way to do this ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Following answer from @Karolis, the development version of the [corrr](https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr) package does something like this using `network_plot()`. Here's an example (including installation of current development version):

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("drsimonj/corrr")
library(corrr)
airquality %>% correlate() %>% network_plot(min_cor = .2)
```

[image]

The plot represents negative correlations with red lines, but clusters the variables based on the correlation magnitude by **using the absolute values of the correlations as the proximity/distance metric**. This is handled by the base function `abs()`. If you think this might help, you can find the relevant code used to produce `network_plot()` [here](https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr/blob/master/R/cor_df.R).

Aside, I'm planning to release the updated version of `corrr` soon so you can access `network_plot()` after install straight from CRAN (`install.packages("corrr")`).

Answer (score 1):

#### One way

Transform your correlations so that -1 will become 0 and 1 still be 1:

```
cors <- (cors+1)/2
```

This way negative correlations will be interpreted as "lowest association". If instead -1 and 1 should both be viewed as "association" then you can take the absolute value of your correlation matrix:

```
cors <- abs(cors)
```

#### Another way

Use a different clustering algorithm. One candidate - hierarchical clustering since it operates on a distance matrix. You have a correlation matrix. So to start you should obtain distances:

```
dists <- as.dist(1-cors)
```

Then do the clustering:

```
htree <- hclust(dists)
plot(htree)                # inspect the result visually.
groups <- cutree(htree, 5) # 5 here is desired number of groups.
```

#### Also

Check out the package "WGCNA" which stands for "weighted gene coexpression network analysis". It has some useful functions for obtaining clusters out of "network" data.